# Canceling Support for old app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Lets assume that I have apps that I have on offer on the Apple App Store. Again, lets assume that I no longer want to support an app and that I am removing the app from the app store.

If my app no longer works or functions correctly after dropping support, is there a way I can suggest deleting the app or are their penalties for having apps that behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sign into your Apple Developer Account and review the License Agreements there.

> License Agreements
>
> The license agreements of the iOS Developer Program and Mac Developer Program detail your obligations and responsibilities as a member. The latest agreements can be reviewed in Member Center.
>
> [Sign in to Member Center](https://developer.apple.com)

From the looks of it though, it is pretty generic protect Apple and Apple's Brand and Good Will. If you received any additional agreements when your app was approved to go on the App Store, then review them as well.

From the looks of it though, and from wha articles in trade publications indicate, many developers just walk away from their apps.

As it sounds like you are trying to do the right thing, hypothetically of course, I do recall that one app that I had, Catch Notes, did post a notice to their landing page on the App Store that their product was no longer going to be supported. If you are able to make updates or adds to the page, then that is likely the place to do it. Also Catch Notes no longer appears on the App Store, so there is some process for removal.

Here are some news reports that made the tech sites.

[Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2013/08/03/catch-note-taking-app-shuts-down/)

[CNET](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/export-your-data-from-catch-notes-before-it-shuts-down/)

[Techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/31/evernote-competitor-catch-com-shuts-down-its-note-taking-apps-company-heading-in-different-direction/)

Check with an Apple representative. There may be a way that the app can be frozen from future downloads, to allow sufficient time for the app's page to be seen by the current user base without expanding it. It is also possible that they are able to message your user base through their records of the App Store purchases. If there is security risk and you feel that the users should completely remove the app, then this is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

[OneNote](https://itunes.apple.com/app/microsoft-onenote-listen-handschriftliches/id410395246?mt=8) by Microsoft did something clever when they discontinued their iPad-only app: they changed the app icon to include an exclamation mark in an update and when you opened it it gave you a message that there was a new version, with a link.

So maybe you can change the app icon as well but instead of a new version link you can just suggest deletion.